# Array coding challenge that needs to be solved in O(n) complexity

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

We are given an array consisting of N numbers, and a number X. We need to find an index K in this array that divides the array into two parts(0 to K-1, and K-1 to N-1) as such:

> Number of elements equal to X in the first part = Number of elements not equal to X in the second part.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> A = (5, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), X = 5
>
> Answer: K= 4
>
> (5, 5, 1, 2) contains two X's.
>
> (3, 4, 5)  contains two non X's.
> ```
>
> Such K always exists according to the problem description. The solution needs to have an O(N) complexity. O(N^2) solution is too easy, yet I could not find the O(N) one.

Here's what I have so far:

```
int function(int X, vector<int> &A) {
    int k = 0;
    vector<int> indices;
    long count = A.size();
    int number_of_x= 0;
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        if(A[i]==X)
            number_of_x++;
    }
    long part_one_x = 0;
    long part_two_nonx = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        if(A[i]==X)
            part_one_x++;
        part_two_nonx = (count-i) - (number_of_x - part_one_x);
        if(part_one_x == part_two_nonx)
            k = i;
    }


    return k;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hint: do a first pass through the array and count the number of Xs. Then find the answer on the second pass.

Comment: The assignment is suppose to be completed by you. Try to solve it by yourself and ask specific questions if you face any problem.

Comment: Jeetendra, the deadline has already passed, and it's a coding challenge that I don't have access to. It just got stuck in my mind. samgak, I did as you stated, yet I did not know what to do in the second pass.

Comment: If you count the number of Xs up to current K, can't you calculate the non-Xs in the remainder, if you know the total number and the size of the array?

Comment: Here's my O(n^2) solution: int k = 0;
    vector<int> indices;
    long count = A.size();
    int size = count;
    int one = 0, two = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        k=i;
        one =0;
        two=0;
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
            if(A[j]==X){
                one++;
            }
        }
        for(int j=i;j<count;j++){
            if(A[j]!=X){
                two++;
            }
        }
        
     if(one==two)
         break;
    }
    
    return k;

Comment: samgak, I know how do that too. Yet, your solution is gonna end up to be of O(n^2) time complexity yet again since you have to test for each K(there are N indices).

Comment: Just keep a running total of the number of Xs up to position K. the number of non Xs in the remainder is (N-K) - (total Xs - running total Xs)

Comment: samgak, thanks. I got it. I kept reiterating over the array twice in the second pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider your example...

```
 A = (5, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

If you consider the first element - 5 - then we know any solution must have one non-5 value at the other end, so we work backwards to find the first non-five, keeping track of the "front" and "back" locations we're working at...

```
 A = (5, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
      ^              ^
```

So, we've balanced the 5s so far with the non-5s as we work in from the ends.  Now we look at the next position on the left, which is also a five, so we move the right-hand position left until we find another non-five:

```
 A = (5, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
         ^        ^
```

Now we advance the left-side position looking for another five, but hit the right position before finding one, so the "right-side" position is a solution.

Comment: Yeah, that seems like another way of doing it.